# Show that the following map is a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x-1)x + y$$

where $g:\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{Z}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$

Attempt: I am only having problems with proving the injectivity part so that is all I'm going to write up here.

Assume $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ mapped to the same point in the codomain:     $$\implies g(x_1,y_1) = g(x_2,y_2) \\ \implies \frac{1}{2}(x_1-1)x_1 + 1 = \frac{1}{2}(x_2-1)x_2 + y_2 \\ \implies x_1^2-x_1 + y_1 = x_2^2-x_2 + y_2$$         this is the step where I am stuck. I know I need to show $(x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)$ but I haven't seen how to do that here.

Comment: On the second line, why is it $+1$? Shouldn't it be $y_1$?

Comment: This is not injective. $g(3,1)=g(1,4)=4$.

Comment: @misakov yes it shoukd be $y_1$. kittyL, acording to munkres it is supposed to be, so if you want to take it up with him....

Comment: @kittyL it says it is in munkres

Comment: Well I have no desire to do that.... Is $\mathbb{Z}^+$ the set of all positive integers? Also, shouldn't you have $2y_1$ and $2y_2$ in your last line? Am I missing some notations here?

Comment: In mathematics argument from authority does not work. Just in general, no function of the form $f(x)+y$ can be injective, since the image of every vertical line is almost onto in the sense that it omits only finitely many values.

Comment: Indeed, no need for "it's supposed to be", as KittyL has kindly provided indisputable proof that the function is, in fact, *not* injective. Which may explain some of your difficulties...

Comment: Then i suppose the issue is how could such a mistake show up in 2 editions of his book and not be corrected, especially when it is a key example for the section.

Comment: @dc3rd: It’s not a mistake; see my answer.

Comment: @kittyL just out of curiousity is there some structured way that you were able to come up with that example?  or did you just plug away at numbers?

Comment: I just plugged in numbers. There are four unknowns and one equation. It's very easy to do that.

Comment: I actually transformed it to $(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2-1)=2(y_2-y_1)$, if that could be of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood Munkres’ argument. He does not say that the function $g$ is a bijection from $\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+$ to $\Bbb Z^+$: it’s a bijection from $A$ to $\Bbb Z^+$, where

$$A=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+:y\le x\}\;.$$

Note that this disposes of **KittyL**’s example, since $\langle 1,4\rangle\notin A$.

It is then to be combined with the bijection

$$f:\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+\to A:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle x+y-1,y\rangle$$

to yield a bijection $g\circ f:\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+\to\Bbb Z^+$.

The second illustration in his Figure $7.1$ shows the set $A$ and the order in which the function $g$ enumerates. In order to see what’s going on, it may help to realize that

$$\frac12(x-1)x=\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}k\;,$$

the total number of points in the columns to the left of $x$.

**Added:** In this case it’s probably easier to show injectivity of $g$ directly, by showing that if $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\ne\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$, then $g(x_1,y_1)\ne g(x_2,y_2)$. Suppose that $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle\ne\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$; there are two cases.

- If $x_1\ne x_2$, we may assume without loss of generality that $x_1<x_2$. Show that in this case $g(x_1,y_1)<g(x_2,y_2)$; use the fact that $y_1\le x_1$.
- Then consider the case $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't that mean in order for the composition to be bijective that each function has to be as well? Well i guess from what you are saying it is not the case

Comment: @dc3rd: Both functions *are* bijections between their stated domains and codomains. The function $g$ is not a bijection between $\Bbb Z^+\times\Bbb Z^+$ and $\Bbb Z^+$, but it’s not intended to be: it’s a bijection between $A$ \and $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: Yes i agree with that, but what went wrong in my effort to show its injectivity? I was successful in doing surjectivity.

Comment: @dc3rd: In this particular problem your approach, while normally a very reasonable way to try to prove injectivity, probably isn’t the easiest. I’ve suggested an alternative in the addition to my answer. (By the way, you do have an algebraic error in the last line of your calculation: it should be $2y_1$ and $2y_2$0.)

Comment: Lesson in going down my list of tools. Direct didn't work so try contrapositive, etc. Thanks. Actually to add, how were you able to assume $x_1 < x_2$?

Comment: @dc3rd: You’re welcome.